# collision bounds with python?

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine, physics

I have a plane and I want to set its collision bounds programmatically (I have some other objects in my scene and I want it to act as a floor). How do I do this? Couldn't really find anything conclusive online...

Thanks!

Comment: Please indicate which fields/values specifically you want to update via python. Screenshots, etc.

Comment: Do you mean the collision shape of a rigidbody?